# Skype 4.3 DBUS Interface: does ALTER CALL SET_OUTPUT works?

Tags: linux, audio, skype, dbus

As stated [here](http://community.skype.com/t5/Linux/Having-trouble-signing-in-Retirement-of-older-versions-of-Skype/td-p/3439685) on the Skype website, there is a mandatory update for all skype clients to version 4.3, because the old clients are not able to connect anymore.
I updated my client on my GNU/Linux Ubuntu 12.04 64bit and started testing the dbus API I was using to connect to the skype client. 
From my tests it seems that some of the dbus API stopped working, but I'd like someone else to confirm my statement. (myabe I'm doing something wrong)

What I normally do, to use the skype client as an engine is to use the DBUS command:

**ALTER CALL  SET_OUTPUT PORT="[some_tcp_port]"**

**ALTER CALL  SET_INPUT PORT="[another_tcp_port]"**

The above command are sent via dbus to skype once the call is up and running
The effect should be that skype redirect the raw audio data (in/out) to the configured tcp ports. That way my software can interact with the skype audio flows.

With *version 4.3* of the skype client the **commands does not return an error**, but all I get on the out channel is white noise

I also tried the command varian: **FILE="[some_file].wav"** but I'm still getting a non empty  wav file apparently containing only white noise (at a very low volume). (I played the file with 'play' 'mplayer' and 'audacity')

Does anyone succeeded in using the dbus API to get the skype audio data with the new client 4.3?
Do you have any idea of alternative solution, in the event the above dbus command are not working anymore as expected?